# Corrupted 2D Char Array After Cycle

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char

i'm writing a simple C program where i'm getting the names of the places(lugares) that have been raining, this is just a practice exercise, the thing is that somehow after the cycle where i get the amounts of pluviosity(pluviosidad) the 2d char array of places(lugares) gets corrupted and its first element loses its content and ends up with garbage, I've been thinking of why this happens in the last 4 hours trying to fix this and I don't see why it happens. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

PD: As far as i'm aware of a 2D Char array works like this [sizeofthearray][lengthofeachelement] so I don't know if somehow i'm making this array unstable, since i'm just using the %-10s to format the outputs. And the lengths of its contents aren't even beyond to 12-15 characters i placed 25 just in case i need more when it gets evaluated.

```
const int nDias = 5;
const int nLugares = 3;
int i, j;

// Arrays Creation
char lugares[nLugares][25];
float pluviosidad[nLugares][nDias];

// A) Data loading
for (i = 0; i<nLugares; i++){

    printf("Ingrese el Nombre del Lugar %d:\n", i + 1);
    gets_s(lugares[i]);
    fflush(stdin);

}

// Somehow after these 2 cycles finish, the "lugares" 2d char array gets corrupted. (I noticed this when doing a debugging session in visual studio)
for (i = 0; i<nLugares; i++){

    system("cls");

    for (j = 0; j<nDias; j++){

        printf("Ingrese pluviosidad para %s en el dia %d: ", lugares[i], j + 1);
        scanf_s("%f", &pluviosidad[j][i]);

    }

}

// Output Data

printf("\t\tLugares\n");
printf("%-10s", "Dias");

// and here I try to see its contents and in this case of 3 elements on the lugares 2d char array, the first element loses its contents and ends up with garbage. 
for (i = 0; i<nLugares; i++)
    printf("%-26s", lugares[i]);
```

Comment: note `char *gets_s( char *str, rsize_t n );`

Comment: `scanf_s("%f", &pluviosidad[j][i]);` → `scanf_s("%f", &pluviosidad[i][j]);`, `gets_s(lugares[i]);` → `gets_s(lugares[i], sizeof lugares[i]);`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @CoolGuy it worked out changing the index order in scanf_s but how can I store the values per row? i thought that doing it in the way i posted meant like pluviosidad[0][0],pluviosidad[1][0], so it fills it up per row then goes [0][1], [1][1], [2][1],[3][1], etc

Comment: @NeptaliD You forgot to interchange the loop conditions. Use `for (i = 0; i<nDias; i++){ for (j = 0; j<nLugares; j++){ scanf_s("%f", &pluviosidad[j][i]); } }`

Comment: @CoolGuy thanks so much! it worked, i see now why that happened